# Best Source Engine Tutorial Books/Sites?

Tags: c++

I want to get into Source Development. Anyone know any good sites for tutorials on it? I already know a few.. Just thought I would ask incase you guys know of any that might be better. 
 Thanks :)

Comment: do you mean "Source Engine" the one from Valve?

Comment: Yep.1 more to go

Comment: Please, read the rules for stack exchange. Questions in the format "which is the best" are not questions for this website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I'd recommend you start browsing through the official steam forum and valve's developer wiki:**

- [Valve Developer Community](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Main_Page)
- [Steam Users' Forums > Steam Tool Discussions > Source Coding](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=195) 
  *(There are really good threads in there, take advantage of the search!)*

**You can also find tutorials here:**

- [Interlopers.net](http://www.interlopers.net/tutorials/)
- [Jailbreak:source Development Blog - Programming Tutorials](http://www.jailbreaksource.net/blog/?page_id=1145)
- [ModDB Source Engine Tutorials](http://www.moddb.com/engines/source/tutorials) *(Take a look at the coding category's)*